# Is it possible to transport Star San in checked in luggage?

Tags: starsan, transport

I wonder if it is possible to transport Star San in checked luggage for an intercontinental flight?

I plan to buy a couple of bottles in the US and fly back to Europe and I wonder if it's possible.

Comment: How much are you talking about? It can't be used as a weapon, it's basically a cleanser. I would put it in checked baggage and not worry about it. Probably the worst that would happen is they would take it away from you. You can by that stuff in Europe you know.

Answer (score 1):

While **inquiring with the FAA or other appropriate authorities is the only way to get a proper answer** to that question, offhand my thought would be "No." Star San is a blend of phosphoric acid and dodecylbenzenesulfonic acid. Since acids are classified (under aviation and other regulations) as corrosive liquids I expect this would not be allowed.

Whether or not you can get away with it is of course another matter, but it's not a gamble I myself would want to take, especially not in the US.